# How to insert the drawable above the text in CheckedTextView?

Tags: android, checkedtextview

This is my XML code:

```
    <CheckedTextView 
android:id="@+id/checkBLC"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/baloncesto"
android:checked="false" 
android:checkMark="@drawable/checkbox_blc"/>
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444466/how-to-customize-a-set-drawable-position-checkedtextview)

And i Try this, but not working:

```
android:checkMarkDrawable="drawableTop"
```

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try  android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image"  

  <CheckedTextView 
        android:id="@+id/checkBLC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/baloncesto"
        android:checked="false" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image"
        android:checkMark="@drawable/checkbox_blc"/>
```

Comment: That is work, but my image appears duplicated. The solution is remove android:checkMark=@drawable/checkbox_blc and implement setOnClickListener in java code